# CS:GO - Skill group after only 9 wins?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

This is part of a screenshot which is several years old that I sadly lost (it's not faked). I never knew you could be awarded a skill group after only 9 wins.

[image]

How is that possible? Did I play so well that the system decided it only needs 9 "samples"?

Comment: You lose wins when you queue with players that get VAC/OW banned in the future. Could you play 9 games legit, one with a known cheater and get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Counter-Strike Wikia states that](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Competitive#Skill_groups):

> Players without a skill group are limited to two competitive matches that result in wins or draws per day until they are placed in a skill group by winning 10 matches to get a rank (or drawing a match after the 9th win).

I'm assuming that like stated in the parentheses, you won 9 matches, and then got a draw, leading to you getting a rank, as well as, displaying only 9 wins on your profile.

Comment: This can very well be, although I cannot remember. I don't think the "2 matches per day" rule was in effect back then as well, but I could be wrong.